# Amazon Bedrock models access request fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, model, request, amazon-bedrock

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8x1Q.png)My request is failing from Amazon Bedrock. It is only for third-party models like `jurrasic`,  meta models, stability diffusion but for Amazon models like titan is accessible. I have changed also my billing details but its not solved.

[image]

Comment: [Model access - Amazon Bedrock](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/bedrock/latest/userguide/model-access.html)

Comment: not working. I have tried all thing for models access but my request is failing againa and again.